# Accept user input Range

Tags: swift

I want to accept user input in a range, but keep on getting error:

Cannot convert value of type `Range<Int32>` to expected argument type `Range<_>`

I am learning Swift but I did not understand the different scenarios to convert `UITextField` to text and maybe integer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var Range1: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Range2: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TheNUmber: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var OutletLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func Guess(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var R1 = (Range1.text! as NSString).intValue
        var R2 = (Range2.text! as NSString).intValue
        //print(R1, " ", R2)
        
        var answer = Int.random(in: R1..<R2)
        // I tried my best to use custom range from UItext field but did not work.
        //I need more help.
        print ("Random Number: \(answer)")
        
        var turn = 0;
        
         if(((R1>1)&&(R1<1000))&&((R2>1)&&(R2<1000))){
            
        
        for i in 1...5{
            let guess = (TheNUmber.text! as NSString).intValue
            turn = i;
        
                
            //let guess = (TheNUmber.text! as NSString).intValue
            if(guess == answer){
                OutletLabel.text = ("Yes, it is \(answer).")
                OutletLabel.text = ("It took you \(turn) tries.")
                break
            }
            else if(guess>answer){
                OutletLabel.text = ("Lower!")
            }
            else if (guess<answer){
                OutletLabel.text = ("Higher!")
            }
            else{
                
                continue;
            }
            
            
            }
        if (turn > 5){
            OutletLabel.text = ("Sorry, it was \(answer).")
        }
            }
    
    else{
    OutletLabel.text = ("Keep the numbers between 1 and 100.")
    }
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func Reset(_ sender: Any) {
        self.Reset (sender)


}
```

I am not sure about this error. Please help me with the range.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `intValue` returns an Int32, not an Int. So change

```
    var R1 = (Range1.text! as NSString).intValue
    var R2 = (Range2.text! as NSString).intValue
    var answer = Int.random(in: R1..<R2)
```

To

```
    let R1 = Int((Range1.text! as NSString).intValue)
    let R2 = Int((Range2.text! as NSString).intValue)
    let answer = Int.random(in: R1..<R2)
```

Even better, don't use NSString or `intValue`. Use Swift.

```
    let R1 = Int(Range1.text!)!
    let R2 = Int(Range1.text!)!
    let answer = Int.random(in: R1..<R2)
```

Be aware that this code can crash — for example, if the user types "howdy" instead of an integer. But you need to deal with that.

Your code has other issues, but at least you will get past this one.

Comment: Thank You matt. I will take care of the input type as well.